# Using Google as Base Layer with Openlayers 3.11.x (lastest)

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, google, basemap

It's possible with Openlayers 3.0 like: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/google-map.html

But I want to use lastest version (3.11.x) of OpenLayers and Google Base Layer.
Not working with lastest like:
http://bl.ocks.org/elemoine/e82c7dd4b1d0ef45a9a4

Any suggestion? Or should I use any other basemap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this library that does what you want: https://github.com/mapgears/ol3-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

update : now ol3 supports google maps have a look at group

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ol3-dev/wub3KnS0NWA